# How to tell which one of the same type of exception was thrown?

Tags: java, exception

Let's say we have a constructor/method which throws `IllegalArgumentException`s on different occasions:

```
class MyClass {

    MyClass(char char1, char char2) {
        if(condition1 on char1 and char2) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("condition1 failed");
        }
        if(different condition2 on char1 and char2) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("condition2 failed");
        }
        ...
    }

}
```

If I wanted to construct an instance of `MyClass` with invalid arguments, how would I tell which exception was thrown?

```
try {
    MyClass clazz = new MyClass('a', 'a');
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    // which one?
}
```

An ugly solution would be checking the detail message, or in `IllegalArgumentException`'s case, checking the provided cause, or using different types of exception (which doesn't seem appropriate in e.g. a parsing method). Is there a general solution to this problem?

Comment: Why do you think you want to do this?

Comment: You have basically listed the options. You can also subclass `IllegalArgumentException`.

Comment: @JoeC I want to parse some data and my method throws ParseExceptions for different reasons. I want to know what actually caused it and present the user with an appropriate message, which getMessage() isn't.

Comment: @AlexShesterov I wanted to avoid having to create a custom exception but if that's the best option, I'll go with it.

Comment: Surely the solution is to put appropriate messages in your exception in the first place?

Comment: They are only appropriate for the developer, not for the user.

Answer (score 1):

you could write you own specific exceptions for both cases and thereby extend illegalArgumentException

edit: as  Alex Shesterov already stated

Answer (score 0):

You can check `e.getMessage()` in your catch block.